# gVim - show position marker of matched search terms

Tags: search, vim, position, marker

Is there functionality, plugin or ways in gVim to show markers of matched search terms, which point out their rough positions in the buffer? For example, when search "foo" in the buffer, the feature put markers along with the vertical scrollbar. Each marker indicates an matched "foo". When you scroll to that position, you see a "foo" in the buffer. With this feature I can easily tell the distribution pattern of the term visually, where the current term is relatively in the document and approximately how many occurrences.

If no such feature, is there way to manipulate scrollbar and other GUI components of gVim in plugin?

In Firefox the similar feature is done by [Search Marker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-marker/?application=firefox&id=1823) (outdated), [XUL/Migemo](https://web.archive.org/web/20181102191552/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xulmigemo/) (outdated) or [FindBar Tweak](https://web.archive.org/web/20181102042142/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/) (up-to-date) extensions.

UPDATE:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/3/3698.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/116/116848.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 As much as I want to see this in gvim, I don't think this is possible without tweaking the very source of gvim. But I'd love to see an answer for this :)

Comment: BTW, this feature is also by default available in Google Chrome.

Comment: I like the idea so much that I've created upstream bug. Feel free to comment there. Let's see if someone will be willing to implement it: https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=191&thanks=191&ts=1388501313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the distribution, you could try:

```
:g//#
```

this will show the lines where the search pattern is found.

Comment: Thank you! It is good to have the global search trick. But you have to first remember the current line number, look for it in the left column and get the idea of distribution. I think it is not comparable to visual ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `:set hlsearch` to get highlighted search terms.

Also try pressing `^G` to see the line and column of the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. However, highlight keyword does not give me position of matches outside the screen. It is good for small files, not for large files. The cursor position is only for current match, not others. Plus I do not care about column number, just line number.